# Liferay iOS sign-in: onSuccess is not called after signIn

Tags: ios, xcode, liferay

I am new to liferay. Trying the liferay iOS SDK 7.0.3, I was trying to follow the brief tutorial at https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/invoking-liferay-services-in-your-ios-app

but got stuck early on, with the signInWithSession method.

After establishing a session with `[[LRSession alloc] initWithServer: authentication: initWithUserName: password:]`

Then I have

```
[session
 onSuccess:^(id result) {
     NSLog(@"signIn success");        
 }
 onFailure:^(NSError *e) {
     NSLog(@"signIn failure, and error is %@", e);
 }
 ];

[LRSignIn signInWithSession:session callback:session.callback error:&error];
```

When the username/password combination is wrong, the onFailure gets called, and it prints the error

> signIn failure, and error is Error Domain=com.liferay.mobile.sdk Code=2 "java.lang.SecurityException" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=java.lang.SecurityException}

But when a correct username/password combination is used, the onSuccess block does NOT get called. I don't see "signIn success" in the console log.

My imports are

```
#import "LRBasicAuthentication.h"
#import "LRSession.h"
#import "LRSignIn.h"
```

Any ideas what may be happening and what I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gah, it was a bug in the iOS SDK 7.0.3! See https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/71261220 . Apparently, it is fixed in 7.0.4.

At least now I know about the liferay forums ..

Comment: use cocoapods and get 7.0.4